# JMeter Listener - create error file only if error occurred

Tags: jmeter

I have View Results Tree for errors only, Errors are checked and it saves the errors

But if there's no errors the file is created with headers

Can I mark something to write to error file only if an error occurred?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untick `Save Field Names (CSV)` button

[image]

The file will still be created but it will be empty (0 bytes) if there are no errors in your test.

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

---

If you don't want the file to be created, the solutions are in:

- going for [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener)
- or checking the file size somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) and if it's empty - remove it using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)